# clone() не запускает функцию

Tags: linux, c

Clone() не запускает функцию но возвращает id = 1

Система: 4.8.0-46-generic #49~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:50:48 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
 on virtual box

Program out :

```
ok id 1
opened
opened
status - 3
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/resource.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #define _GNU_SOURCE
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <dirent.h>
    //#include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    //#include <linux/sched.h>
    #include <sched.h>

    #include <string.h>

    #define STACKSIZE 1024*1024
        pthread_mutex_t lock;
    int doSomeThing(char *arg)
    {

     //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("Func start");

        struct dirent * de;
        DIR * dir;
        if ( ( dir = opendir(arg) ) == NULL ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Forbidden, no permission!\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("%s: \n",arg);
        char dirstrs[256][256];
        int dscount =0;
        while ( de = readdir(dir) )
        {
            printf("%s\n", de->d_name);

            if(de->d_type == 4 && strcmp(de->d_name,".") !=0 && strcmp(de->d_name,"..") !=0)
            {
            char dirstr[256];
            strcpy(dirstr,arg);
            strcat(dirstr,"/");
            strcat(dirstr,de->d_name);
            strcpy(dirstrs[dscount],dirstr);
            dscount++;
            //printf("%s\n",dirstr);
            //doSomeThing(dirstr);
            }
        }
        printf("\n\t");
        closedir(dir);

        printf("dirstrs:\n");
        for(int i=0;i<dscount;i++)
        printf("%s\n",dirstrs[i]);


      //  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    //while(1);
        return 0;
    }

    int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char dir[256];
    getcwd(dir,256);
    strcat(dir,"/proc");

    //doSomeThing(dir);


        /* if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)
        {
            printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    */
    int id;
    char *stack=malloc(STACKSIZE);
    char *stackhead=stack+STACKSIZE-1;
    if(id = clone(&doSomeThing,stackhead,SIGCHLD,0) >= 0)
    {
    printf("ok id %d\n",id);

    }else
    printf("fail\n");
    //clone(doSomeThing,((char*)malloc(500)) + 200,CLONE_FS|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_VM|CLONE_FILES|SIGCHLD|__WCLONE,dir);

         FILE *file;

         if( file = fopen("rd.c","rw"))printf("opened\n");
             else printf("not opened\n");
         if( file = fopen("rd.c","rw"))printf("opened\n");
             else printf("not opened\n");
        fclose(file);
        int status;
        waitpid(id,&status,0);
         printf("status - %d\n",status);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Ну, `id = 1` это потому, что  присваиванеие внутри if надо писать в скобочках -- `if ((id = clone(...)) >= 0) ...` (но это все же означает, что clone выполнилась нормально)

Comment: изменил, теперь выдает id процесса 2814, но все равно не запускает фукнцию

Answer (score 0):

Ответа не заслуживает, но поскольку в комментариях код не вставить, то вот простейший пример (у меня `Linux wubu 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` работает) использования `clone()`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

static int
do_clone (void *a)
{
  fputs("do_clone\n", stderr);
}

int
main ()
{
  char *stack = malloc(10000);

  pid_t id = clone(do_clone, stack + 10000, SIGCHLD, 0);
  if (id < 0)
    perror("clone");
  else {
    puts("run clone");
    sleep(1);
  }

}
```

У меня выводит

```
avp@wubu:hashcode$ gcc clone.c 
avp@wubu:hashcode$ ./a.out 
run clone
do_clone
```

попробуйте у себя.

Comment: Ваш пример работает. До перезагрузки делал подобную программу - она не работала, после перезагрузки стала работать но программа из поста так и не заработала. Починил с помощью флагов CLONE_FS|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_VM|CLONE_FILES|SIGCHLD|__WCLONE вместо SIGCHLD, вопрос с SIGCHLD остается открытым.
P.S. Версия 4.8.0-46-generic #49~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:50:48 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: SIGCHLD тут вообще ни при чем. Это номер сигнала, который система пошлет родителю, когда функция запущенная в clone завершается. Можете поймать, задав обработчик перед clone. А вот как вы вообще планировали **делать с CLONE_VM** (одно и то же адресное пространство, т.е. подобно pthread) **или без** (это как fork)?

Comment: @Iridiscent, комментарий-то я забыл снабдить @ nick так что не знаю, получили ли вы его (но этот снабдил). Вообще, в приведенном в вопросе  виде код не рабочий. В clone вы передаете в doSomeThing arg как 0, а там используете аргумент arg